# Facebook app: Cannot add localhost domain with my live server domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

Whenever I tried to add localhost domain with my live server domain in my facebook app domain it shows me error "App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct these domains: localhost". 
Is it possible to add the localhost domain along with my live server domain?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A good way to solve this is to use a Test App: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/

Test Apps have different settings, so you can easily use localhost without an additional platform as workaround.

Comment: What if I want to use localhost in my live facebook app. Is there is any workaround?

Comment: You could add another platform for it that does not really exist (Website + Page Tab, for example), but i highly suggest using a Test App and do it the proper way.

Comment: My problem with the test app is that it's practically another app with its own settings. If I use another 3rd party service (exm. AWS Cognito), I need to replicate my Cognito App Client as well.